# Why sporadically I get a null reference exception on items.count

Tags: list, splistitemcollection

```
SPList List = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Lists.TryGetList(listname);

SPQuery camlQuey = new SPQuery();

camlQuery.RowLimit=10;

SPListItemCollection items = List.GetItems(camlQuery);

if (items.Count> 0)

{

//do something

}
```

For some reason After I deployed this code it works fines two times and after that it throws the exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by the user code
Stack trace:

   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.SetVar(String bstrUrl,
String bstrName, String bstrValue)

   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData()

   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.get_Count()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your CAML query yields no results and hence your condition **items.count** will through an exception. you an check if the items object is null and then get the count. verify your query is correct with tools like CAMLBuilder to test

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("your site"); 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List spList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List Name"); 
clientContext.Load(spList); 
clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 

if (spList != null && spList.ItemCount > 0) 
{
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery(); 
   camlQuery.ViewXml = 
      @"<View>  
            <RowLimit>5</RowLimit> 
      </View>";  

   ListItemCollection listItems = spList.GetItems(camlQuery); 
   clientContext.Load(listItems); 
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
}
```